# Serializing a list in a class

Tags: java, serialization

I am a newbie to the world of serialization, I have a query which may be repetitive but please help me.I have a class named ABC which consists of a list.I want to serialize the list so that I can transfer that list over the network. Below is my class..

```
Public class Abc {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
}
}
```

should I go for serializable or externalizable interfaces?

Comment: where is the problem? You have implemented the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: Several points: 1. please correct your spelling, especially some punctuation marks would be helpful. 2. Please provide more information on how you'd want to transfer that list. 3. [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

The list you defined is a local variable in the main method. local variables are not serialized. If you need the list to be serialized, you'll need to define it as an instance variable of the class ABC and define the class ABC as serializable by implementing the Serializable "interface".

```
public class Abc implements Serializable {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public Abc() {
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
    }
}
```

This way, the class Abc can be serialized, sent over a network, then deserialized correctly. Note that List/ArrayList are part of the java's collections and are typically "Serializable". For custom classes, they also need to implement the Serializable "interface".

Answer (score 0):

If your client is a Java client, you just have to mark your class as `implements Serializable`. Otherwise you have to marshal your data using XML or JSON. There are many libraries for marshalling/unmarshalling. For XML you can use JAXB or XStream, and for JSON you can use Jackson, XStream and many more libraries.